# What's the meaning of BSTR, LPCOLESTR, and others?

Tags: winapi

What's the meaning of BSTR, LPCOLESTR, LPCWSTR, LPTSTR, LPCWCHAR, and many others if they're all just a bunch of defines that resolve to wchar_t anyway?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LPTSTR and LPWSTR and similar defines are really just defines. BSTR and LPOLESTR have special meanings - they indicate the the string pointed to is allocated in a special way.

String pointed to by BSTR must be allocated with SysAllocString() family functions. String  pointed to by LPOLESTR is usually to be allocated with CoTaskMemAlloc() (this should be looked up in the documentation to the COM call accepting/returning it).

If allocation/deallocation requirements for strings pointed to by BSTR and LPOLESTR are violated the program can run into undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 13):

- `LPTSTR` indicates the string buffer can be ANSI or UNICODE depending on the definition of the  macro: `UNICODE`.
- `LPCOLESTR` was invented by the OLE team because it switches its behaviour between char and `wchar_t` based on the definition of `OLE2ANSI`
- `LPCWSTR` is a `wchar_t` string
- `BSTR` is an LPOLESTR thats been allocated with SysAllocString.
- `LPCWCHAR` is a pointer to a single constant wide character.

They're actually all rather different. Or at least, were at some time different. Ole was developed - and needed - wide strings while the windows API was still Win16 and didnt support wide strings natively at all.

Also, early versions of the Windows SDK didnt use wchar_t for WCHAR but unsigned short. The windows SDK on GCC gets interesting as - im led to belive that GCC 32bit has a 32bit wchar_t - on compilers with 32bit wchar_t, WCHAR would be defined as an unsigned short or some other type thats 16bits on that compiler.

Comment: This seems like the more accurate answer regarding 'LPCOLESTR'.

Comment: "BSTR is an LPOLESTR"  or is that meant to say LPCOLESTR ?

Comment: Well, its not fair to ask questions now 15 years later. I am pretty sure BSTRs were not const. Much to my own surprise at the time. I do remember finding some Sys*String functions that would not have worked if given an actually immutable string which I thought might have been the pragmatic reason.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN's page on [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28VS.85%29.aspx) might provide clarification as to the differences between some of these data types.

> **LPCWSTR** - Pointer to a constant null-terminated string of 16-bit
>   Unicode characters.
>
> **LPTSTR** - An **LPWSTR** if UNICODE is defined, an **LPSTR** otherwise.