# How do I create a variable or constant of type LPOLESTR?

Tags: c++

I need `LPOLESTR` (Long Pointer OLE String) as an argument to a simple function call.

According to [The Complete Guide to C++ Strings, Part II - String Wrapper Classes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3004/The-Complete-Guide-to-C-Strings-Part-II-String-Wra)

> OLECHAR is a Unicode character (wchar_t)
>
> LPOLESTR is a string of OLECHAR (OLECHAR*)

So I should be able to do this:

```
int demo(LPOLESTR ptName) {
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    
    demo(L"Visible");
}
```

But I'm getting a compile error:

> (const wchar_t[8])L"Visible"
>
> argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPOLESTR"

or maybe I'll try a variable:

```
LPOLESTR lVis = L"Visible";
```

But I get this compiler error:

> (const wchar_t[8])L"Visible"
>
> a value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "LPOLESTR"

I have `#include <string>` at the top.

This seems like it should be a simple thing but I've been Googling all morning and can't find the answer. How do I create a variable or constant of type LPOLESTR in C++?

Comment: If `LPOLESTR` is `wchar_t*`, you can't assign a `const wchar_t*` to it. You could remove the `const`ness by casting if you are sure it will not be changed by the function. Otherwise, why not use a `wchar_t*` or `wchar_t[]` without const?

Comment: @KarstenKoop Ok and how would I do that. Sorry I'm a noob.

Comment: [See also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607266/whats-the-meaning-of-bstr-lpcolestr-and-others). It seems a `LPOLESTR` implies something about the way it was allocated, similar to `BSTR`.

Comment: @KarstenKoop: A `BSTR` is a very different beast indeed, containing a header before the actual string section.

Comment: Are you using some framework like MFC or ATL? Then there should be helper classes for this.

Comment: @ I saw something on BSTR earlier

Comment: @KarstenKoop I'm not using either MFC or ATL.

Comment: const violation in C++ (not in C), consider `LPCOLESTR`.

Comment: So why do I see sample code without the `const_cast` and it seems to work for them?

Comment: use `demo( OLESTR("Visible") )` and check that you have  UNICODE macro defined.

Comment: @VictorGubin #define OLESTR(str) L ## str, argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPOLESTR". I think I must be missing something fundamental in my setup that others normally have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that `LPOLESTR` is a `typedef` for `wchar_t*`.

A compiler will not allow you to convert a `const wchar_t*` to a `wchar_t*` *without* an explicit `const_cast`.

Writing, using an alternative type `LPCOLESTR`:

```
LPCOLESTR lVis = L"Visible";
```

will fix the immediate compilation error as would the more Windows-like and probably preferred by Windows programmers.

Using a `const_cast` is, in general, not advisable but you will get away with it if the function documentation states that it does not attempt to modify the data passed to it.

Comment: D_Bester: If I were you I would only take the const_cast at the point of invocation of an API funcion, then check the function documentation to make sure it doesn't modify the string.

Comment: @PasserBy: Removed, and fixed with the proper Windows typedef.

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me until I use `LPOLESTR lVis = const_cast <wchar_t *>(L"Visible");` so maybe edit that in. Or maybe there's another reason for that.

Comment: I did check to make sure I have UNICODE macro defined

Comment: @D_Bester: Note the **C** in LPCOLESTR

Comment: Well then I would need `demo(const_cast <LPOLESTR> (lVis2))` because the argument needs to be `LPOLESTR`

Comment: Indeed. At the function call site I'd probably use a C-style cast ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When I compile in Visual Studio 2022 and by using standard C++20, I get similar error messages.

```
*Error (active) E0167   argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPOLESTR"*
```

[image]

I needed to pass through the compilation by avoiding "strict const-qualification" conformance by using compiler option **"/Zc:strictStrings-"**

Project Properties | C/C++ | Command Line -- add the compiler option.
[image]